# java networking, calls to write in average take 4x longer than calls to read, is it normal?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, nio, java-io

To be more specific, i have written a server with java NIO, and it works quiet well, after some testing i have found out that for some reason, in average a call to the SocketChannels write method takes 1ms, the read method on the other hand takes 0.22ms in average.

Now at first i was thinking that setting the sent/receive buffer values on Socket might help a bit, but after thinking about it, all the messages are very short(a few bytes) and i send a message about every 2 seconds on a single connection. Both sent and receive buffers are well over 1024 bytes in size so this can't really be the problem, i do have several thousand clients connected at once thou.

Now i am a bit out of ideas on this, is this normal and if it is, why ?

Comment: Since you're using NIO, I assume that you're using a Selector and write only when the key is ready for write, or are you using blocking calls? Would you get us a sample of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using Wireshark to eliminate variables.

Comment: He's already using NIO.  So write should just be copying the data into a buffer and letting the TCP/IP stack deal with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

@Nuoji i am using nonblocikng-io and yes i am using a Selector, as for when i write to a channel i do the following:

Since what i wrote in the second paragraph in my post is true, i assume that the channel is ready for writing in most cases, hence i do not at first set the interest set on the key to write, but rather try to write to the channel directly. In case however that, i can not write everything to the channel (or anything at all for that matter), i set the interest set on the key to write(that way the next time i try to write to the channel it is ready to write). Although in my testing where i got the results mentioned in the original post, this happens very rarely.

And yes i can give you samples of the code, although i didn't really want to bother anyone with it. What parts in particular would you like to see, the selector thread or the write thread ?